# Resumable uploads with WebClient class

Tags: c#, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to upload a video but getting an empty result from the server (0 bytes).

For step 1, i'm calling the api like that:

```
var json = vc.UploadCreate("/me/videos", "tus", 3021075, "POST");
```

"tus" is the approach, "3021075" is the file size. I'm saving the upload_link & uri, and then making the second request like that:

```
string filepath = @"C:\videoplayback.mp4";
var rslt = vc.UploadPatch2(uploadlink, filepath);
```

My UploadPatch2() method:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0");
wc.Headers.Add("Upload-Offset", "0");
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/offset+octet-stream");
wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ******");

var file = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

var result = wc.UploadData(upload_link, "PATCH", file);
```

When trying to send "PATCH" request as it says in the API, it fails with the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

When doing it with "PUT", there is no exception but "result" gets 0 bytes back from the server.

Comment: Read step 2 under "Using the resumable approach", the content type should be the one that i used. Anyway i tried your answer and it's giving the same 404 error

Comment: Sorry, I misread it, yes you are using correct content type. Additionally, do you get `HTTP 201 status code` upon creating the video request?

Comment: You will have to use `upload.upload_link` in the response of create video API to upload your file.

Comment: Yes, i get 201 status code and i'm using upload.upload_link. it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems this is just a bug with Vimeo's API.
The file gets uploaded, but the response is error 404.